# Apache2 rewrite returns filename extension

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I really don't understand where I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to apply a rule to

```
http://localhost/prezzo/account/1
```

so that it is rewritten as

```
http://localhost/prezzo/account/test.php?user=1
```

I'm using UniformServer as WAMP. I placed the `.htaccess` file in the subfolder I'm working on (*prezzo/account/*) with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (\w+)/?$ test.php?user=$1 [L]
```

[htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=bea6bf82-29a4-46da-9e8e-006628fa9309) reports that the rule is applied correclty.

But when I go to the URL `http://localhost/prezzo/account/1` and `test.php` is loaded - which contains simply

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['user'];
?>
```

it returns the string "**php**" instead of "**1**".

If I try with

```
RewriteRule ^prezzo/account/(\w+)/?$ prezzo/account/test.php?user=$1 [L]
```

I get **404 not found** although [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=1b62ff50-6405-41da-be55-dea128a63be4) reports that the rule is applied correctly and the URL is rewritten as

```
http://localhost/prezzo/account/test.php?user=1
```

that if I copy/paste in the address bar it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I go to the URL `http://localhost/prezzo/account/1` and `test.php` is loaded [...] it returns the string "php" instead of "1".

Yes, this is expected with the rule as posted.

This appears to work in the "htaccess tester" because that tool only makes a single pass through the file, which is not how a real server works.

> ```
> RewriteRule (\w+)/?$ test.php?user=$1 [L]
> ```

When you request `/prezzo/account/1` then...

1. The request is rewritten to `test.php?user=1`
2. The `L` flag causes the rewrite engine to start over using the rewritten URL (`test.php?user=1`) as input to the next round of processing.
3. The request is rewritten to `test.php?user=php` since the regex `(\w+)/?$` captures the `php` part of `test.php`. (The `\w` shorthand character class excludes dots and the regex is not anchored.)
4. The `L` flag causes the rewrite engine to start over using the rewritten URL (`test.php?user=php`) as input to the next round of processing.
5. The request is rewritten to `test.php?user=php` (again).
6. Since the URL has passed through unchanged the rewriting process stops and the request is finally rewritten to `/test.php?user=php`.

#### Solution A - Use the `END` flag

One solution is to simply use the `END` flag  (Apache 2.4) instead of `L` to prevent the rewriting engine from "looping". It will stop as soon as the directive is processed. For example:

```
RewriteRule (\w+)/?$ test.php?user=$1 [END]
```

#### Solution B - Make regex more specific

The other solution (or as well as) is to make the regex more specific, so that it doesn't match `test.php`. ie. Only match the URL format you are expecting.

The regex `(\w+)/?$` would seem to be too generic, as it is basically just matching the last group of letters/numbers on the URL-path. If you only want to match digits (a "user-id") then you could make the regex more restrictive and match only digits instead.

You should also anchor the regex at the start, so that it matches a whole path segment, rather than just capturing the last part that matches. In fact, simply anchoring the above regex would have also resolved this, since `test.php` would have failed to match because `\w` does not match dots.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ test.php?user=$1 [L]
```

This will match digits only in the last path segment.

---

> If I try with
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^prezzo/account/(\w+)/?$ prezzo/account/test.php?user=$1 [L]
> ```
>
> I get 404 not found although htaccess tester reports that the rule is
> applied correctly and the URL is rewritten

If the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/prezzo/account` subdirectory (as you stated) then the above will never match and the directive does nothing.

That testing tool assumes the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root only. If your `.htaccess` was located in the document root and not the subdirectory, then that directive would indeed be OK.

In a *directory* context (eg. `.htaccess`) the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path *relative* to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

---

***Aside:***

In your link, the entire file would seem to be:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
> #RewriteRule . index.php [L]
>
> RewriteRule (\w+)/?$ test.php?user=$1 [L]
> ```

The first rule is commented out so does not apply here. However, if you uncomment that first rule then the rules are in the wrong order. Since a request for `/prezzo/account/1` would first be rewritten to `index.php` and you'd have the same problem as before.

The order of rules is important.

Comment: Thank you MrWhite, I would never work it out by myself. The reason I commented `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is that i need to pass as parameter a HEX string long 300 bytes (such as account/be486ebc06e39c37...) but the server reports 'Forbidden' because it's too long (although the browser may have URLs up to 2048 bytes). I read that this may be due to `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` so someone suggested to remove it, but it did not fix the problem.